# How to authenticate Api Key in the constructor?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wsdl, code-access-security

I have a Webservice class. It has methods like AddStudnet, RemoveStudnet, UpdateStudent etc. These methods take parameters like StudentID, FirstName, LastName etc. All these methods have one common parameter - Api Key. The constructor does not take any parameters. So, in all my methods I'm authenticating the Api Key. If it's not a valid key an error message is returned.

Instead of authenticating in every method, how can I authenticate the api key in the constructor and prevent the object from getting instantiated? When I was researching on preventing the object from getting instantiated I came across throwing exceptions. If I go with throwing exceptions, will the webservice be exposed to any security vulnerabilities? Is there a different approach to prevent the object from getting instantiated if a invalid api key is passed?

Answer (score 0):

Here is two article that will give you a kick start and show you basic implementation of API Key :

First by Ron Jacob :

[How to do API key Verification](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/06/14/how-to-do-api-key-verification-for-rest-services-in-net-4.aspx)

Second, How to use the API Key with the constructor:

[How To Authenticate API Key In The Constructor](http://amilagm.com/2012/04/better-way-to-do-api-key-verification-in-wcf-webhttp-services/)

Most important thing is to verified the key in each call with this :

```
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall
```

That line of code is forcing a call to the constructor on every request, so every request the API is verified.

Hope that help you.